# Django FormView success_url parameter advice

Tags: django

I am converting an old project with Class Views and I want to know if the pattern I am using is "safe".

In brief I have a class View like this (code simplified ):

```
class FileAddHashedView(FormView):
    """This view hashes the file contents using md5"""

    form_class = FileUploadForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('vault-show')
    template_name = "vault/add.html"
    filebox_random= 0

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('vault-show', kwargs={'random': self.filebox_random})

    def form_valid(self, form):

        instance = form.save(commit=False)

        #generate a random number
        rng = random.SystemRandom()
        #TODO: must catch exception here
        instance.random=rng.randint(0, sys.maxint)

        instance.save()
        #TODO: check what is the proper way to generate the parametric URL
        self.filebox_random=instance.random
        messages.success(
            self.request, 'File hashed and uploaded!', fail_silently=True)

        return super(FileAddHashedView, self).form_valid(form)


    def form_invalid(self, form, **kwargs):
        messages.error(self.request, 'Upload failed ...', fail_silently=True)
        return super(FileAddView, self).form_invalid(form)
```

And the corresponding views that gets activated:

```
class VaultStatus(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'vault/vault.html'

    def get(self, request,random):
        # retrieve object info

        data = {
            'filebox': FileBox.objects.get(random=random)
        }
        return render(request,self.template_name,data)
        #return render_to_response('vault/vault.html', {'random': random});
```

Now my question is: is there a better way in **get_success_url** to get the **self.filebox_random** without relying on a class attribute?
Is this thread-safe?

Answer (score 0):

You're not using a class attribute here. Even though you've defined `filebox_random` at class level, by setting a value to that name within an instance method in Python you're actually creating an instance attribute with the same name, which hides the class-level one. (Although I'm not actually sure why you're defining the class attribute in the first place).

Django does quite a lot of work behind the scenes to ensure that class-based views are thread-safe, so there is no danger in setting instance attributes.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I was just wondering if there was a different procedure to "pass" that instance random parameter to the success URL avoiding the instance attribute.
Something like:
`
    def get_success_url(self,parameter):
        return reverse('vault-show', kwargs={'random': parameter})
`
But oky if is thread safe I won't bother asking for more!